# How to find 1 cluster in group of data points

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, simulation

I am trying to find 1 cluster in a group of data, and I am not sure how to do this without selecting all of the data points to be within the cluster (i.e. the particles lost at the beginning of the simulation).

I have attached a gif of the cluster I am trying to identify in my code, and looking to find its root-mean-square radius.

[image: fig of system]

Answer (score 1):

A cluster means is a group of data distinguishable from other clusters. If there can be only 1 cluster, it must be the group of all. In other words, a cluster is meaningful when there are other clusters.

So you cannot find the only 1 cluster. You should distinguish multiple clusters and pick the 1.

In this perspective, it seems like you want to have two clusters, one cluster of dense points around the origin (0, 0), and the other cluster of all other sparse points scattered far from the origin. For this kind of data, you can use [spectral clustering](https://rpubs.com/sandipan/271634).

Try [sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn-cluster-spectralclustering) with various `gamma`.

With the following data

```py
X = np.array([
    [0, 0], [0.1, 0], [0, 0.1], [-0.1, 0], [0, -0.1],  # hopefully cluster 1
    [5, 0], [0, 5], [-5, 0], [0, -5]                   # hopefullycluster 2
])
```

I could successfully distinguish them into two clusters by using `gamma=5.0`

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(
    n_clusters=2,
    gamma=5.0,
    assign_labels="discretize",
    random_state=0
).fit(X)

print(clustering.labels_)
```